# PeterBlum SelectedIndexCondition Not Equal functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, peterblum

Right now we are using the PeterBlum SelectedIndexCondition to control whether or not some controls are displayed using the following snippet:

```
PeterBlum.DES.MultiFieldStateController fsc = new PeterBlum.DES.MultiFieldStateController();

PeterBlum.DES.SelectedIndexCondition cnd2 = new PeterBlum.DES.SelectedIndexCondition();

cnd2.Index = desiredIndex
cnd2.ControlToEvaluate = ControlToEvaluate//ListBox, dropdown, etc
fsc.Condition = cnd2;
```

I'd like to be able to achieve this same functionality except to fire when the desired index IS NOT set.  I cannot simply create a bunch of Conditions for each index other than the one I specify due to the way this is dynamically being done in my application.

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score -1):

You will probably get better results if you post your question to [Peter's Yahoo Forum](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/peterblum/). In my experience, he will get back to you very quickly with a good answer.